# Update between 2 databases using dblink not working

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, dblink

Basically I have 2 databases each containing 2 tables. I need to update what's in database 2 using a table in database 1.

Below is database 1 table 2 (db1 ta2)

```
pid  |   pname  |  pcompany  |  clocation  |  did  |   name
 1       Pirates    Argos        London        1       Mary
```

Database 2 table 1 (db1 tb1)

```
pid  |   pname        |  pcompany  |
 1       Ba Ba Black      Argos
```

Now I need to update 'Ba Ba Black' to Pirates meaning I need to update **db2 tb1** from **db1 ta2**.

```
UPDATE tb1 
SET name = ta1.name
WHERE ta1.name = (SELECT ta1.name FROM dblink('port=5432, dbname=db1 user=postgres  password=12345',
'SELECT name FROM ta1'))
AS t1 (a integer, b character(20), c integer)
WHERE pid = 1;
```

But I have this error:

> ```
> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "AS"
> LINE 5: AS t1 (a integer, b character(20), c integer)
> ```

Any idea what I might be messing up?

Comment: Why the confusing example with `db2 tb1` and `db1 ta2` instead of something like `db1 tb1` and `db2 tb2`? Can you untangle that?

Comment: as I have 2 different tables in each database. the ta1 and ta2 are in db1 (a) and the bs go with db2

Comment: That's relevant for your application, but not for the sake of this question ..

Comment: I don't know what I'm doing wrong though... why that error is coming up

Comment: You don't need this `(a integer, b character(20), c integer)` after the `AS t1`

Comment: So i'll remove the whole AS statement? as I tried that and now i Have a different error

Comment: @JorgeCampos: A column definition list is required for dblink, but this one didn't match the statement and the closing parenthesis came early.

Answer (score 2):

Add table / column aliases and (most probably) a WHERE condition like this:

```
UPDATE tb1 b
SET    name = a.pname   -- maybe you want to update *pname* instead?
FROM  (
   SELECT *
   FROM   dblink('port=5432 dbname=db1 user=postgres  password=12345'
               , 'SELECT pname FROM ta1 WHERE pid = 1')
          AS t(pname text)
   ) a
WHERE b.pid = 1;
```

Assuming type `text`. Adapt to your actual type.
And no *comma* in the [connection string](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-CONNSTRING).
I am not linking a to `b` since `a` returns a single row here.

Comment: I've tried it. when I put AS ta1 (name character(20)) but leaving everything like yours it says this: ERROR:  column "name" does not exist
CONTEXT:  Error occurred on dblink connection named "unnamed": could not execute query.

Comment: @DodoSerebro: Seems like your column name is actually `pname`?

Comment: It's still giving me a MISSING FROM Clause at the SET line (line 2)

Comment: @DodoSerebro: Sorry, forgot the wrapping SELECT statement that's needed here to provide the column definition list.

Comment: It's saying now  ERROR:  subquery in FROM must have an alias
LINE 3: FROM  (
              ^
HINT:  For example, FROM (SELECT ...) [AS] foo.

Comment: @DodoSerebro: That's odd. My query *has* an alias. You sure this isn't something lost in translation or an outdated version?

Comment: I'm using postgresql 9.3 I think it's the latest one.

Comment: @DodoSerebro: I meant an outdated version of the query I provided - since I updated it. Anyway, I am off for lunch. Good luck for now.

Comment: I literally copied yours again: now this is showing:
ERROR:  column "pname" does not exist
CONTEXT:  Error occurred on dblink connection named "unnamed": could not execute query.

Comment: @DodoSerebro: That shouldn't be possible according to your definition in the question since *both* tables have a column named `pname`.

Comment: I noticed a mistake in mine SET pname = a.pname in which I was omitting the p in the LHS pname. This popped up though ERROR:  column "pname" of relation "tb1" does not exist
LINE 2: SET    pname = a.pname

Answer (score 0):

I worked the following way:

```
DO$$
DECLARE
 sql_statement TEXT;
BEGIN
 sql_statement:='UPDATE public.ta2 SET name='''||NEW.name||''' WHERE pid=1;';
PERFORM public.dblink('port=5432 dbname=db1 user=postgres  password=*',sql_statement);
RETURN NEW;
END;
$$
languaje plpgsql;
```

You can consult this link: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/plpgsql-trigger.html