# Update column using dblink

Tags: postgresql, inner-join

I am using below reference to update 2 columns (customer name, service) at table cust_eq_memory_dy.

loopback at table msrouterlistfinal2 will match address at cust_eq_memory_dy.

Can someone help me on this as I got the syntax error at or near "FROM"?

[Update between 2 databases using dblink not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20840261/update-between-2-databases-using-dblink-not-working])

```
UPDATE cust_eq_memory_dy B 
SET customername = A.customername 
WHERE B.ipaddress = A.loopbackip 
FROM ( 
  SELECT *
  FROM DBLINK ( 'host= 10.X.80.160 user=123 password=123 dbname=postgres',
'select customername, serviceid, loopbackip FROM msrouterlistfinal2 ')
 as temp (
 customername character varying (100),
 serviceid character varying (50),
 loopbackip character varying (30) )
 )A
```

Comment: The `where` needs to go _after_ the `from`

Comment: Yes ! It works. :)

Answer (score 5):

if you are using postgres I highly recommend you to use the **WITH** sentence.

```
    WITH A as ( SELECT * FROM DBLINK ( 'host= 10.X.80.160 user=123 password=123 dbname=postgres', 'select customername, serviceid, loopbackip FROM msrouterlistfinal2 ') as temp ( customername character varying (100), serviceid character varying (50), loopbackip character varying (30) ) )
UPDATE cust_eq_memory_dy B SET customername = (SELECT A.customername FROM A WHERE B.ipaddress = A.loopbackip);
```

Check this link for more information.
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/queries-with.html

Comment: got error message   missing FROM-clause entry for table "a".

Comment: You are right, I missed the select from the table A.     WITH A as ( SELECT * FROM DBLINK ( 'host= 10.X.80.160 user=123 password=123 dbname=postgres', 'select customername, serviceid, loopbackip FROM msrouterlistfinal2 ') as temp ( customername character varying (100), serviceid character varying (50), loopbackip character varying (30) ) )
UPDATE cust_eq_memory_dy B SET customername = (SELECT  A.customername FROM A WHERE B.ipaddress = A.loopbackip);

Comment: I start got error :  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression. But, i will try to test even though I solve the problem as advised by a_horse_with_no_name